# How to get deleted files back in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

Please help me I'm in a big problem :(

I lost a very important `.twig` file in my Symfony project after clearing the cache. Is it possible to get it back?

Please any idea may help me, I have to represent my work tomorrow and I can't recode it now.

Comment: Have you checked phpstorm's [local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/viewing-local-history-of-a-file-or-folder.html)? If you're lucky, it's still there (or at least a recent version of it is)

Comment: Just follow the steps on that link. Select the folder the file should be in, and choose the Local History option from the VCS menu.

Comment: is there any other solution? because i didnt find the old file

Comment: If you're not using version control (e.g. Git or Subversion) and you don't have a backup anywhere, then I'm afraid not. If you're **very** fortunate, you might be able to recover it using an undelete tool. There are plenty of options provided in other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+recover+deleted+files

Comment: What makes you think that clearing the cache deleted any files in your src or app directory?

Comment: I used EASE US DATA RECOVERY but it gave me the current version of file.

Comment: the file is not deleted, it's empty!!!! After clearing the cache when I oppened the file I found it empty, I don't understand why

Comment: you did not edit  the original file but the cached one, so you have t make sure to edit the files in `src` dir